# Using ValueAnimator to animate LayoutParams results in requestLayout() improperly called

Tags: android, android-animation, layoutparams

I am trying to animate a change in height of a particular View. I've set up a ValueAnimator with an Evaluator and I update the LayoutParams at every pass of the animation. This, in turn, triggers a requestLayout() call. Before the layout pass has completed however, the next pass of the animation updates the LayoutParams and triggers another requestLayout(). The result is warnings outputted in LogCat as well as the animation not working well. It seems to skip many frames.

```
    ValueAnimator contentHeightAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofObject(new HeightEvaluator(mContentView),
            mContentView.getMeasuredHeight(), (int) (getMeasuredHeight() - (actionBarHeight + destinationY)));
    contentHeightAnimator.setDuration(duration);
    contentHeightAnimator.setInterpolator(mInterpolator);
    contentHeightAnimator.start();

...

private static class HeightEvaluator extends IntEvaluator {

    private View mView;

    public HeightEvaluator(View v) {
        this.mView = v;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer evaluate(float fraction, Integer startValue, Integer endValue) {
        int num = (Integer) super.evaluate(fraction, startValue, endValue);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = mView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = num;
        mView.setLayoutParams(params);
        return num;
    }

}
```

What is the best way to animate layout changes?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one I used to animate a menu splitting up so that another, lower-level menu can be inserted

```
    final int newBottomMargin = (int)(origBottomMargin + halfMargin);
    final int newTopMargin = (int)(origTopMargin + halfMargin);

    splitUp = new Animation() {
        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params =  (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) btnShopWireless.getLayoutParams();
            params.bottomMargin = (int)(newBottomMargin * interpolatedTime);
            btnShopWireless.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
    };

    splitDown = new Animation() {
        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params =  (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) btnShopBundles.getLayoutParams();
            params.topMargin = (int)(newTopMargin * interpolatedTime);
            btnShopBundles.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
    };
```